# Problem occur when implementing a omp parallel nested loops

Tags: c++, openmp

I am learning omp parallel in C++. I want to assign values to a 4D array named "F" with dimensions (N, M, K, K). When I implement it without parallelization, the resulting matrix of F[N-1][M-1][0:K-1][0:K-1] is

```
0.0001 600 600
600 0.0001 600
600 600 0.0001
```

However, when it is implemented using omp parallel for, the resulting matrix is

```
0.0001 75 75
75 0.0001 75
75 75 0.0001
```

where the off dignoal elements are wrong. Here are codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

double**** make4Darray(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4) {
    double**** tmp;
    tmp = (double****)malloc(a1 * sizeof(double***));
    for (int n = 0; n < a1; n++) {
        tmp[n] = (double***)malloc(a2 * sizeof(double**));
        for (int m = 0; m < a2; m++) {
            tmp[n][m] = (double**)malloc(a3 * sizeof(double*));
            for (int k = 0; k < a3; k++) {
                tmp[n][m][k] = (double*)malloc(a4 * sizeof(double));
            }
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

void delet4Darray(double**** tmp, int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4) {
    for (int n = 0; n < a1; n++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < a2; m++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < a3; k++) {
                free(tmp[n][m][k]);
            }
            free(tmp[n][m]);
        }
        free(tmp[n]);
    }
    free(tmp);
}

int main() {
    int M = 3000;
    int N = 2000;
    int K = 3;
    int nc = 8;

    double A = .0001;
    double B = 0;
    double C = 0;
    double D = 0;
    double**** F;
    F = make4Darray(N, M, K, K);

    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
            B += A;
            C -= A;
            D += A;
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
                for (int k1 = 0; k1 < k; k1++) {
                    F[n][m][k][k1] = B;
                    F[n][m][k1][k] = F[n][m][k][k1];
                }
                F[n][m][k][k] = A;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
        for (int k1 = 0; k1 < K; k1++)
            cout << F[N-1][M - 1][k][k1] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    delet4Darray(F, N, M, K, K);

    // Set the number of cores for parallel
    omp_set_num_threads(nc);
    A = .0001;
    B = 0;
    C = 0;
    D = 0;
    F = make4Darray(N, M, K, K);

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:B, D) reduction(-:C)
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
        for (int m = 0; m < M; m++) {
            B += A;
            C -= A;
            D += A;
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
                for (int k1 = 0; k1 < k; k1++) {
                    F[n][m][k][k1] = B;
                    F[n][m][k1][k] = F[n][m][k][k1];
                }
                F[n][m][k][k] = A;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
        for (int k1 = 0; k1 < K; k1++)
            cout << F[N-1][M - 1][k][k1] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: Leave `malloc`/`free` out of the parallel regions. Also don't create a multidimensional array like this, as it will be non-continuous this way which is bad for cache locality. Instead allocate one big block and do manual indexing or alternatively initialize `tmp` with addresses from the big array (performance might be worse due to the amount of indirections).

Comment: Calculate `B` and `C` as a function of `n`,`m` and `A`, then remove reduction (`reduction(+:B, D) reduction(-:C)`) and your parallel code will give the same result as the serial one. Note that `D` is not used at all.